# django-filter finds a match if you enter the full name

Tags: python, django, django-filter

django-filter finds a match if you enter the full name. For example, I try to filter by the name "Titanic" and I type "Titan" into the search, nothing will be found until I type in the entire text "Titanic". **How do I search by partial match?**

```
class ProjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    address__name = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='address', lookup_expr='street')
    approve = django_filters.BooleanFilter(field_name='approve')
    ordering = django_filters.OrderingFilter(choices=CHOICES, required=True, empty_label=None,)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = [field.name for field in Project._meta.fields]
        order_by_field = 'address'
```

**View**

```
class FilterTable(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    table_class = TableAll
    model = Project
    template_name = "table.html"
    filterset_class = ProjectFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

By default it uses `exact` lookup. https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#lookup-expr Try to use `icontains` for example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#icontains

Answer (score 0):

By default django filter data with exact match if you want to filter with partial query match you need to add icontains lookup expression

icontains provided filter data from queryset with partial string match.

So, your code becomes like this...

You need to add `lookup_expr='icontains'` instead of `lookup_expr='street'`

```
class ProjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    address__name = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='address', lookup_expr='icontains')
```